# Task 'installRelease' not found in root project 'ReactNativeStarter'. Some candidates are: 'uninstallRelease'

Tags: react-native

I get the above error when I use the command `react-native run-android --variant=release` like it said in the react native docs. I signed my key just like it said in [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) but it's not working.

I also couldn't use the command `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` directly from my project folder. I had to do `cd android` and then `gradlew assembleRelease`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From react-native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#testing-the-release-build-of-your-app)

> Note that --variant=release is only available if you've set up signing
>   as described above.

Verify whether you have followed the steps mentioned in the documentation properly.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't see the line `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` I forgot to put that in.. Hours of stressing for a stupid mistake

Comment: Bad luck.. These silly mistakes are hard to catch :)

Comment: @SinanSamet Dear sir, thank you for saving my day. I just did the same mistake.

Comment: Documentation link not working please update.

Answer (score 7):

For your second issue, try this if you are using Windows:

```
cd android && gradlew assembleRelease
```